# What methods or actions we should avoid when build a wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

There are many tutorials talk about how to build wordpress site from a theme or scrath.

But I want to know what's the worst way to build a wordpress site?
I heard people saying: Using hooks instead of override. I am not sure if this is true. If this is true, then we should aoid override files？

WTF wrong with people give me negative 1? This is a reasonable question. If you don't want to help, just leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to build custom themes is to get a book and learn the right way to use template hierarchies and custom post types. Make use of the loop using [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Use WordPress template tags , methods and functions if they exist rather than writing your own.

The worst way to build a theme is to reinvent the wheel, writing your own code for things that already exists. Not only will it take a lot longer, but it will more more likely to break during updates and harder for other people to understand.